# configure: error: libcrypto not found

Tags: php, compiler-errors, libcrypto

I compile php7 by myself.

1. Download php7 source.
2. yum install libxml2-devel openssl-devel.i686
3. configure

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php7 --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --enable-sockets --with-openssl<br>
```

Then I got an error:

```
configure: error: libcrypto not found
```

I have google this error, but get nothing. Nobody meet with this issue? There must be a little mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I google it and it costs me a lot of time,but get nothing.So guess it must be a little mistake.I review my steps again and find the reason.Share it to guys who may make the same mistake.

The point is:

```
yum install libxml2-devel openssl-devel.i686
```

As is known,i686 is the 32-bit version, and x86_64 is the 64-bit version of the OS.My centOS is 64-bit version,but i installed openssl-devel.i686.

If install openssl with i686 version on 64-bit OS,will get the error:configure: error: libcrypto not found